# Path in unweighed graph : shortest trip from source, back to source, with one point imposed

Tags: python, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

In my unweighed graph, I need from a source vertex to reach an imposed vertex and come back to source.
All vertex may be visited at most once.
(There may be cycles in that graph.)
I want the length of the shortest such path.

Looking for a "fast" algorithm:

I have already made several attempts in Python but not fast enough. ;-)
Latest for instance : generator of all paths from source to imposed point (in order of increasing length), every time I get a new path, compare it with all those already calculated and stop if disjoint.
Good result, but too slow / memory expensive.
Earlier (same issue) : consider sub states with information : position, already been to imposed point or not, set of already visited vertexes... good result too but too slow / memory expensive.

DP solution welcome.

Could not find something with google. Point me to if you know where there is something.

Thanks.

--- example ---

```
e...
#!!#
#!.#
...s
```

This is a maze; you enter at 'e' and need to reach the sword 's' and back to the entrance 'e'.
'#' are unpassable. '!' are traps, when you walk on these, you trigger them and cannot pass again. 
I have turned this into a graph with 5 vertices in this case : e,s, (2,2), (3,2) and (2,3)

--- case where Suurballe algo yields two not disjoined paths ----

```
.....
##!!#
#!!!#
#!!##
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

For unweighted graph shortest path BFS in both directions might be the most efficient solution.

You can use BFS to determine how far every node is from your source.

after you find the path, you can remove every node beside the source and target so you will not repeat a node on the path more than once, and then use BFS from the target back to your source.

The total complexity is linear O(V+E)

more on that:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-unweighted-graph/

Comment: I do not think that works. Some paths cancel any possibility of a way back.

Lately, what I did was to use BFS to find all paths from source back to source.
And stop when first such path is found if it contains imposed point.
Correct, but too slow and too memory hungry. THis is the third attempt (third algorithm I designed that works for simple cases but fails for big cases)

=> So I am looking for a more subtile approach...

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question. You can see that if you trigger the two upper traps on the way in, then .. you just can never get back to the entrance, hence my reserve on your suggestion. I think the problem should be solved with flows etc.. but lack the background to actually do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then I think what you're looking for are node disjoint paths.   The classic algorithm to uncover them was proposed by [Suuballe](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8fe0/35f498ecc7d3b68e5488dc83e1f7facf75e8.pdf).  Another algorithm based on network flow is implemented in networkx: [networkx.algorithms.connectivity.disjoint_paths.node_disjoint_paths](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.disjoint_paths.node_disjoint_paths.html).

Hopefully these pointers solve the problem in your graphs with sufficient speed.

Comment: Yes I did and got very close, thanks. The paper you pointed me to was abit too complicated so I used the wikipedia version which was quite clear.
I saw some variations in other web pages that puzzled me a bit.
However, I do not get the proper result in some cases  (see the initial question)

Comment: Note : it is *node* disjoint path I am looking for, not *edge* disjoint paths. There seems to be a lot of confusion in the web pages I find...